# Unable to display the content from JSP

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I am bringing data from elastic  to a servlet and assigning the data to different variables. Then I am sending this data to a JSP. In the JSP,  with the help of JS, I am creating a form and appending the data to it, and then displaying the form.

It's not appending to the div and also not displaying on the screen. Can anyone tell me what is wrong.

Here's the code.

Serv.java

```
request.setAttribute("list", list);

ServletContext sc = this.getServletContext();
rd = sc.getRequestDispatcher("/formdisplay.jsp");
rd.include(request, response);
```

In JSP

```
 <body>
     <script type="text/javascript">



            <c:forEach items="${list}" var="record">

            var eletype = ${record.type};
            var value = ${record.value};

            var divClassResp = {
                    "defSize" : "col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3",
                    "4column" : "col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3",
                    "1column" : "col-xs-12",
                    "4columnLabel" : "col-xs-4",
                    "8columnText" : "col-xs-8"
            };
               var rootElemName = "Text"
               var rootElemLabelName = "Text"

     if(eleType == 'text' && subType == 'text'){
              createTextElement(rootElemName,rootDiv,divClassResp["4columnLabel"],"col-xs-12","col-xs-8",rootElemLabelName,
                      defTextSize,defStyle,divClassResp["defSize"]);

      </c:forEach>

            </script>





<div id="dynamic"></div>

</body>
```

Here is the JS

```
function createTextElement(elementName,parentDiv,labelGridSize,gridSize,textGridSize,labelName,size,style,gridLayout) {

/*
 * Default Layout has an in-line form with 4 columns : see
 * divClassResp[defSize]. With text input there is a 1:2 ration of a column
 * width between label and text-value
 */
    var rootEleDiv = document.createElement(defEle);
    $(rootEleDiv).attr({id:randomNumberFromRange()});

    var eleDiv = document.createElement(defEle);
    $(eleDiv).attr({id:randomNumberFromRange()});

    $(rootEleDiv).attr({'class':defDivClassFormRad + " " + defDivClassError + " "  + gridLayout,
        'display':defDisplayType,'style':style});

    $(defLabelEle).addClass(defDivClassLabel + " " + labelGridSize + " "  
            ).text(labelName).appendTo(rootEleDiv);
    $(eleDiv).addClass(textGridSize);

    $('<input/>', {
        'type': 'Text',
        'size': size,
        'class':defDivClassFormEle,
        'name':elementName,
        'id':elementName
    }).appendTo(eleDiv);

    rootEleDiv.appendChild(eleDiv);

    parentDiv.appendChild(rootEleDiv);

}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to generate the HTML via javascript (which is in turn generated in your JSP). Why don't you just generated the HTML direct?

Comment: Also the JS inside the loop will only work if there is only one iteration. You add vars for each loop. Look in the console and fix the many errors I believe you will find

Comment: Actually, the form has to be customized before displaying. That's why I am generating it through JS. And JSP is used since i have to supply data from servlet.

Comment: rootDiv, subType not defined, value not used. divClassResp  needs to be outside the loop etc etc

Comment: @mplungjan  thanks for the reply but data in the list will change..that's why I have put the vars inside a loop. Also while calling this JSP from the servlet I have used include so it means it's gonna go back and will execute statement there. so how to tackle that?

Comment: It's quite possible to custom the form through javascript after it has been genertated. There is no need for javascript to generate it

Comment: You only vary two vars. They need processing: `<c:forEach items="${list}" var="record">  doSomeProcessing("${record.type}","${record.value}");</c:forEach>` - assuming there are no newlines in any of them. Hit F12 and see the errors and view source

Comment: @mplungjan thanks..just help me with one more thing..okay since my JSP is called again and again, how to display the content. Since I am appending an element to the div at runtime so should I redirect to some other page to display or what.?

Comment: Sounds to me you need to investigate Ajax